# Displaying picture in Reminder notification for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to display an image in the reminder notification page for WP7 using C#? The image should be display along with the reminder title and content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. The Content property looks like it can take any context but nothing other than text will not work.